# How to execute kernel command from Front End?

Tags: front-end

Documentation for Yuri E. Kandrashkin's OptionsExplorer package says to add the following menu commands in MenuSetup.tr:

```
   Item["Options &Explorer", KernelExecute[ToExpression["OptionsExplorer[]"]],
   MenuKey["o", Modifiers->{Control,Command}], MenuEvaluator->Automatic]
```

And I want to accomplish the same thing by a corresponding `` FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands... `` expression in an `` Autoload`PacletManager`Configuration`FrontEnd`init.m ``.

But I don't find any `KernelExecute` function.

How to do it?

Comment: Isn't this just what you get when you type something in a cell in the front end, and hit Shift-Enter? So it is just telling the kernel to run the code inside its brackets.

Comment: If I try to evaluate from a notebook input cell the ``FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands`` expression that includes that `KernelExecute` expression, it colors `KernelExecute` to indicate it's an unknown name. And trying the same thing from the indicated `init.m` seems to accomplish nothing -- but then perhaps I misunderstood what I need as the first argument to `AddMenuCommands`: I used `"Input from Above"`, which is on the `Insert` menu.

Comment: [See this related MathGroup posting](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Sep/msg00173.html). The function `KernelExecute` appears to be undocumented but exists and just tells the main kernel to run its argument. Try adding those commands into the file as instructed and see if it works.

Comment: Rd @Verbeia's comment: the linked MathGroup posting by John Fultz concerns directly editing `KeyEventTranslations.tr`. But I'm not trying to do that; I want a way that makes changes only in `$UserBaseDirectory`, not `$InstallationDirectory`. Hence I'm trying to edit ``Autoload`PacletManager`Configuration`FrontEnd`init.m``. Moreover, I'm trying to insert an Item there that does two things: (1) create a new menu item (on the `Insert` menu); and (2) sets up a corresponding shortcut key -- as I showed in Kandrashkin's code snipped that appears in my question.

Comment: Here's what I added to the indicated `init.m`:
`FrontEnd\`AddMenuCommands[
  "Input from Above", {Delimiter, 
   Item["Options &Explorer", 
    KernelExecute[ToExpression["OptionsExplorer[]"]], 
    MenuKey["o", Modifiers -> {Control, Command}], 
    MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}];`

But after restart (with clean cache) nothing gets added to the `Insert` menu. Did I not properly identify the existing menu keyword in the 1st argument to `AddMenuComands`? Is something else wrong?

Answer (score 7):

You can add the menu command to your Insert menu using `AddMenuCommands` in the following manner.  (These modifications will only persist for the current front end session.)

First a demo function, just creating a dialog:

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["DuplicatePreviousOutput",
  {Delimiter, MenuItem["CreateDialog &Demo",
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute[CreateDialog[{TextCell["Click OK to close"],
       DefaultButton[]}]], 
    MenuKey["D", Modifiers -> {"Control", "Shift"}],
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

(Note the required context specification for MenuEvaluator.)

This version will run OptionsExplorer[]

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["DuplicatePreviousOutput",
  {Delimiter, MenuItem["Options &Explorer",
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute[ToExpression["OptionsExplorer[]"]],
    MenuKey["O", Modifiers -> {"Control", "Shift"}],
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

Comment: *Which* `init.m` among the many in the tree?

Comment: Where's the corresponding `init.m` for Mac OS X to what @Chris Degnen gives in `C:\Documents and Settings\Chris\Application Data\Mathematica\Kernel` for Windows?

Comment: @murray evaluate this: `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel"}]`

Comment: @Chris Degnen: I've just tried this with version 9 and found that -- at least on Windows -- we need to add the FrontEnd context now for `MenuKey` and `Modifiers`, too. Maybe you want add that to this answer?