# How can I set a keyboard shortcut to run a command?

Tags: evaluation, keyboard, system

I want to use this to add a keyboard shortcut to an undo function I wrote. The basic problem is the following:

I have a command, let's say `x=1`, and I want to run the command with a keyboard shortcut. Is there a way to do it?

Editing the KeyEventTranslation.tr file is what I tried.

Adding

```
Item[KeyEvent["z",Modifiers->{Command}],Evaluate[x=1]],
```

does not work.

```
Item[
 KeyEvent["z", Modifiers -> {Command}], 
  FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"x=1"]}]]
```

adds the text x=1 where the cursor is, but it still needs to be evaluated and I need to be at the right place with the cursor.

Are there other ways?

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/how-to-execute-kernel-command-from-front-end) might be related, but I couldn't get anything out of it so far.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are four approaches to setting up keyboard shortcuts.  The last is the best!

**AddMenuCommands**

First examples using notebook manipulation, (as you tried):

This example adds a command to the Insert menu, with a key combination Control+U (normally the underline command).  This addition just lasts for the session, but could be added to an init file.

```
FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["DuplicatePreviousOutput",
  {Delimiter, MenuItem["Evaluate x = 1",
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute[
     nb = SelectedNotebook[];
     SelectionMove[nb, After, Cell]; 
     NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"x", "=", "1"}]], "Input"]];
     SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
     SelectionEvaluate[nb]],
    MenuKey["u", Modifiers -> {"Control"}],
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

Note, you can find the box format like so:

```
ToBoxes[Hold[x = 1]]
```

Out = RowBox[{"Hold", "[", RowBox[{"x", "=", "1"}], "]"}]

This could also be done invisibly like this:

```
FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["DuplicatePreviousOutput",
  {Delimiter, MenuItem["Evaluate x = 1",
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute[
     nb = CreateDocument[Null, Visible -> False, WindowSelected -> True];
     NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"x", "=", "1"}]], "Input"]];
     SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
     SelectionEvaluate[nb];
     NotebookClose[nb]],
    MenuKey["u", Modifiers -> {"Control"}],
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

A quicker version just uses `ToExpression`, (not `Evaluate`, as you first tried):

```
FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["DuplicatePreviousOutput",
  {Delimiter, MenuItem["Evaluate x = 1",
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute[ToExpression["x=1;"]],
    MenuKey["u", Modifiers -> {"Control"}],
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

**KeyEventTranslations**

The notebook manipulation can be implemented in KeyEventTranslations.tr like so:

```
Item[KeyEvent["u", Modifiers -> {Control}], FrontEndExecute[
  FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], After, Cell];
  FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], 
    Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"x", "=", "1"}]], "Input"]];
  FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], Previous, Cell];
  FrontEnd`SelectionEvaluate[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]]]]
```

**NotebookEventActions**

Another approach for adding a keyboard shortcut is this:

```
function[] := x = 1

SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[],
 NotebookEventActions -> {"DownArrowKeyDown" :> function[]}]
```

Setting notebook event actions to command or control key combinations does not appear to be possible.  A shifted key assignment can be made, e.g. Shift+O (just capital "o"):

```
NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "O"} :> ...
```

You can replace `SelectedNotebook[]` with [$FrontEnd](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24FrontEnd.html) (note 'Details') - that adds the assignment to your front end init file.  (To undo, you would need to edit the init file to remove the event assignment.)

**MenuSetup**

Finally -- and this is probably the most obvious -- place `x = 1;` in a file called assign.m and call it from a menu item specified in MenuSetup.tr with:

```
Item["Evaluate x = 1",
 KernelExecute[Get["assign.m", Path -> "C:\\Users\\chrisd\\Documents"]]]],
 MenuKey["u", Modifiers->{"Control"}], MenuEvaluator->Automatic]
```

Alternatively, use `ToExpression`:

```
Item["Evaluate x = 1", KernelExecute[ToExpression["x=1;"]],
 MenuKey["u", Modifiers -> {"Control"}], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Very nice. That definitely works. Perfect would be to not add any text to the notebook. I like that there is no need to edit any system files.

Comment: @jenson_bo - I added a second AddMenuCommands variation which doesn't leave any text in the input notebook.

Comment: Great answer, I tried the invisible option, it works, but since I am using the notebooks name in the assigned  function creating a new document seems to be a problem. I will try the last option later. Thanks. Once the keyboard shortcuts work in a nice way, I think my layman's undo/version control is presentable - but of course can be improved even more.

Comment: @jenson_bo - In the first version, you could delete the created cell like so: `NotebookWrite[nb, 
 Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{RowBox[{"x", "=", "1"}], ";"}]], 
  "Input"]]; SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
SelectionEvaluate[nb];
SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
NotebookDelete[nb]`

Comment: @ Chris Degnen - `SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell]; NotebookDelete[nb]`  That does the trick I think. :)

Comment: I have not tried this yet but there is also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16165/how-can-i-set-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-a-command for adding a menu item