# Evaluating selected expression using keyboard shortcut

Tags: front-end, keyboard

Imagine that in this toy code I want to evaluate just the selected (blue) expression:
[image]

To get as output result: {09/14,09/15,09/16,09/17,09/18,09/19,09/20}

There is some shortcut to do this?
I'm looking for something like <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Mac). But I don't want it to evaluate in place, but as an output. Maybe something that I can put into KeyEventTranslations.tr

Today I have to copy the code to outside the module, or comment the rest of it. In this toy code it's a easy task, but for bigger code it's very annoying to do.

Comment: Maybe you can accept a pallete?

Comment: There have been quite a few instances where I would've really liked something like this, but I was too lazy to automate it. In interactive sessions, you might often also have a global symbol `r` that's the same as in the module. So just doing an evaluation in the same notebook might overwrite the global `r`, which is not desirable. So a possible solution might be to copy selection, create a new notebook with a context unique to the notebook, evaluate, copy result and discard notebook

Comment: @Kuba Hi. I prefer keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Murta Did you read [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16174/187)? I never bind my own shortcuts, but this looks promising. For the first part of your question I probably have a nice solution, although it's currently bound to a button.

Comment: @halirutan Interesting post. As I said in the question, a believe that change the KeyEventTranslation.tr file is one way, but I don't know handle with Cells Execution syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The following will almost do it (the only two problems I did not manage to solve so far are that `Out` values are not printed and previous output cells are not deleted - but these should be solvable):

You can use `CellEventActions`, to effectively override the action for `SHIFT+RETURN`. Here is the code for the `CellEventActions`:

```
partialEvalRule = 
   {"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"} :>
       With[{nb = InputNotebook[]},
         With[{sel = NotebookRead[nb]},
           CellPrint @
              ExpressionCell[#, "Output", CellAutoOverwrite -> True] & @
                 ToExpression  @  
                    If[sel === {},
                      SelectionMove[nb, All, Cell];
                      First[
                         FrontEndExecute[
                            FrontEnd`ExportPacket[
                               NotebookSelection[nb], 
                               "InputText"
                            ]
                         ]
                      ],
                      (* else *)
                      sel
                    ]
         ]
       ];
```

where I used [this excellent answer of John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/how-do-i-extract-the-contents-of-a-selected-cell-as-plain-text/1411#1411) for code extraction from the selection (actually, it might have been better to use this for both branches of the `If`).

Here is how you can set this on a notebook level: create a new notebook

```
nb  = CreateDocument[]
```

Set the option:

```
SetOptions[nb, CellEventActions -> {partialEvalRule}]
```

Now if you start working in that notebook, you will see that you get what you requested, apart from the two issues I mentioned above.

Comment: The `Out` label may be no harder than adding the option `CellLabel -> ToString@"Out"[$Line]` to `ExpressionCell` I think

Comment: @Rojo You might be right, just no time to play more with this, at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this key shortcut added to `KeyEventTranslations.tr` does what you need:

```
 Item[
  KeyEvent["t", Modifiers -> {Control}],
      FrontEndExecute[
              FrontEnd`SelectionCreateCell[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]];
              FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], All, CellContents];
              FrontEnd`SelectionEvaluate[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]];
                     ]
     ]
```

This will work if the result is going to be one cell output, otherwise only first cell will stay. If you want all of them then use:

```
SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], All, **Cell**]
```

but doubled input cell will not be overwritten.

---

I was trying to deal with multiple cell output with tagging input cell and then deleting it just after evaluation but I've faced a problem.

I failed setting `CellTags`. Is the syntax incorrect? Any comments appreciated.

```
 FrontEnd`SelectionCreateCell[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]];
 FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], All, Cell];
 FrontEnd`SetOptions[FrontEnd`NotebookSelection[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]], 
                     CellTags -> "temp"];
 FrontEnd`SelectionEvaluate[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]];
 FrontEnd`NotebookDelete[FrontEnd`Cells[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
                                        CellTags -> "temp", GeneratedCell -> False]];
                 ]
```

Those procedures do what I've decribed, when added to `Pallete`. For complete code go to this answer edit history.

Comment: Hi @Kuba. Your first solution worked nice for one line.

Comment: @Murta Yes it does. Also for multiple lines with only one line as a resut too. Just like the case you provided.