# Can tab just mean "insert tab character"?

Tags: notebooks, autocomplete

Is there a way to set the tab key to simply insert the tab character in a notebook? I often find the sometimes mysterious "features" bound to that key detrimental.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try (for a single notebook)

```
CreateDocument[{},
 NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "\t"} :> 
  NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], "\t"]}]
```

or (for global application)

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd,
 FrontEndEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "\t"} :> 
  NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], "\t"]}]
```

Does this meet your needs? For me it had an effect in `Input` cells but didn't block autocomplete behavior, though if that's what's getting in your way it can be disabled in Preferences.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you map any key that way? Where is this type of thing documented?

Comment: My pleasure. You can catch/handle single key presses, but not combinations like Ctrl + _ (it's been suggested that may be possible in the future). The docs aren't great, but there is some info in the section on `EventHandler`. If you are interested in mapping special keys (e.g. tab) you'll need to refer to them either using regex formats ("\t","\n",etc.) or in Mathematica-ese (see "Structural Elements and Keyboard Characters")

Comment: Thanks for the info. I thought I might try to implement a "block tab" of selected lines (which would be *so* nice). It's been requested [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39876/9150), but they didn't end up using the tab key. I'll have to explore more to find out why.

Comment: @RicoPicone That's an interesting question. It also made me realize I mispoke: you can catch some combinations of keys such as Control (as LeonidShifrin shows in his answer). But I know that it is somehow limited (though I can't remember the details). I must be something like you can't capture the Alt key or Ctrl+Alt.

Comment: @RicoPicone Just took a stab at "block tab": see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48621/5059)