# Code Indentation in Mathematica 11.3

Tags: formatting, pagelayout

How can I indent properly long code in *Mathematica*?
Are there some best practices?

Comment: Use code style cells instead of input style cells and indent manually, as you would in a plain text editor. Or just use a plain text editor.  Alternatively, do not write long code (which is not *always* possible, but when it is, it also makes things more maintainable, so it's good practice).

Comment: By "do not write long code" I meant: break down your code into pieces that are short enough to be easy to understand. Each can live in its own input cell.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Even if your code is all short functions, sometimes it depends on configuration "code" that may be long. In those cases I put my conf is a separate text only cell where I can indent it with spaces at will. For this I convert the cell to InputForm or set the cell style to "code".

Comment: This is a HUGE missing feature in the front end, multi-line indent! How is that not a thing yet?

Comment: @M.R. I thought the front end *does* provide some form of multiline indentation, albeit without any real customizability.

Comment: @Szabolcs If you only knew how much your first comment (about using code style cells) has changed my life! An added benefit is that the code does not jump around nearly as much during editing, something that irked me no end.

Comment: @M.R. related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39876/get-tab-key-to-indent-a-block-of-code

Comment: @M.R. and b3m2a1 and others, stylesheets used in [DevTools`](https://github.com/kubaPod/DevTools)  allow multiline indentation on Tab hit but I didn't advertise it too much because I only tested it in .m/code cells and sometimes selection is not quite right afterwards, indentation is correct though.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a quick plug for some stuff in that question I linked. I have it all built into my GitHub so you can load a thing to let your cells be indentable by:

```
loadIndenter[] :=
 (
  BeginPackage["Indenter`"];
  Indenter`MakeIndentable::usage = "Makes indentable";
  BeginPackage["`Package`"];
  Indenter`Package`$PackageName = "Indenter";
  EndPackage[];
  Get["https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/raw/master/Packages/FrontEnd/StylesheetEdits.m"];
  Get["https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/raw/master/Packages/FrontEnd/IndentableCells.m"];
  EndPackage[];
  )
```

Then with that loaded just make a cell and run:

```
MakeIndentable@yourCellHere
```

And it'll be indentable. Here's a demo:

[image]

Indenting is done by selecting a piece and using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>
Dedenting is done with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>
Toggling between `"\n"` newlines and `"\[IndentingNewlines]"` is done with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

Whenever you try to indent a cell any `"\[IndentingNewlines]"` get converted to `"\n"`-type newlines and I attempt to preserve the formatting if possible (that's the last thing I do in that GIF)

---

#### Indentable notebooks

That function can also make a full notebook or stylesheet indentable. If you open up a Package notebook with this:

```
makeNewPackageNotebook[ops : OptionsPattern[Notebook]] :=
 With[
  {
   flops = FilterRules[{ops}, Options@Notebook]
   },
  FrontEndTokenExecute["NewPackage"];
  SetOptions[Notebooks[][[1]], flops];
  Notebooks[][[1]]
  ]
```

You can immediately make it indentable by:

```
MakeIndentable@
 makeNewPackageNotebook[]
```

This'll hang for a bit while it finds and makes a stylesheet for the package.

Alternately you can scrape off a `Notebook` what makes it indentable and pass that in directly:

```
$indentingStyleSheet =
  With[{nb = CreateDocument[{}, Visible -> False]},
   MakeIndentable@nb;
   (NotebookClose[nb]; #) &@Options[nb, StyleDefinitions]
   ];

newIndentablePackage[ops : OptionsPattern[Notebook]] :=

 makeNewPackageNotebook[
  Flatten@{ops, $indentingStyleSheet /. (StyleDefinitions -> 
        "Default.nb") -> (StyleDefinitions -> "Package.nb")}
  ]
```

Now any package notebook made with that function will have this indentation autoconfigured.

Comment: This is great :)

Comment: @M.R. you might enjoy the edit, too

Comment: This is definitely something that should be considered for the Front End but with Shift+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab so as to be consistent with most editors that have this feature.

Comment: @Edmund both TextWrangler and Atom use Command-] and Command-[ so I used that scheme, but had to find things for which there already were `"MenuKey"` bindings. In principal one could add one's own bindings to get these in cleaner.

Comment: Admittedly my suggestion from using Microsoft products.

Comment: @Edmund I'm sure any consistent scheme would be good :) Obviously making things play nicely with this indentation was tough with the box-language but I'm sure if I can do it John Fultz can do it better (there are no doubt cases mine misses that I've never seen).

Answer (score 9):

#### GeneralUtilities`HoldPrettyForm

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
HoldPrettyForm[Row[Table[Table[Plot[Sin[i x] Cos[j x], {x, 0, Pi}], 
  {i, 1, 5}], {j, 1, 3}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. It can be applied to large code blocks and the Output cell can be promptly converted into Code cell. However, some basic customization on the output would be welcome. In particular, changing the tab based indent into a double space indent. I just did a google search for more information on HoldPrettyForm, but it seems that this page is the single page in the internet about this function!

Comment: @Davi, you can see the definition(s) of functions used in `HoldPrettyForm` using `PrintDefinitions[HoldPrettyForm]`.  To replace tabs with `" "` you can use `RawBoxes@Map[# /. s_String :> StringReplace[ s, "\t" -> " "] &, #, 
    All] &@ToBoxes@ HoldPrettyForm[ Row[Table[
     Table[Plot[Sin[i x] Cos[j x], {x, 0, Pi}], {i, 1, 5}], {j, 1,  3}]]]`

Comment: ... or  use `ClearAll[replaceTabs];
replaceTabs = RawBoxes@*(Replace[#, s_String :> StringReplace[ s, "\t" -> " "], 
      All] &)@*ToBoxes;
replaceTabs @ HoldPrettyForm[Row[Table[Table[Plot[Sin[i x] Cos[j x], {x, 0, Pi}], {i, 1, 5}], {j, 1,  3}]]]`

Comment: Thanks, @kglr. Essentially it works. Just a small issue: when applying to any term that contains a pattern like 'x_', (e.g., `f[x_] := x`), an error is returned. I slightly extended your approach to avoid this issue. The following should work:  `replaceTabs = 
  Replace[#, s_String :> StringReplace[s, "\t" -> "  "], All] &;
replacePatterns =  ReplaceAll[#,  InterpretationBox[string_String, somethingElse__] :>  string] & ;  RawBoxes@replaceTabs@replacePatterns@ToBoxes@HoldPrettyForm[
     f[x_,y_] := <Insert your long code here>
     ]`

Answer (score 4):

As already said in other answers, this is very subjective, but here a tip I find very useful for coding plots: I put every command on a different line, and I use the comma separator at the beginning of the line.
This is quite handy for commenting parts of the code, to enable/disable some plot options quickly (i.e. just commenting the whole line and not commenting through 2 lines).

This is an example of what I mean:

```
DensityPlot[(Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x,-4,4}, {y,-4,4}
 ,PlotRange -> All
 ,PlotPoints -> 150
 ,LabelStyle -> {24, Black}
 ,FrameStyle -> Black
 ,ImageSize -> 300
 ]
```

If I want to comment the ImageSize for example, I just select the whole line and comment it:

```
DensityPlot[(Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x,-4,4}, {y,-4,4}
 ,PlotRange -> All
 ,PlotPoints -> 150
 ,LabelStyle -> {24, Black}
 ,FrameStyle -> Black
 (*,ImageSize -> 300*)
 ]
```

However, for doing the same thing having the commas at the end of the line, I would have to do this:

```
DensityPlot[(Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x,-4,4}, {y,-4,4},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 150,
 LabelStyle -> {24, Black},
 FrameStyle -> Black(*,
 ImageSize -> 300*)
 ]
```

This ofc holds just for the last option line (the other ones are easily commented in both the cases), but if you have nested options, like having epilogs etc in your code, you may have "more than one last option line" in the code, and then having the comma at the beginning of the code becomes more useful :)

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling many are going to find things they don't like slightly about my indentation, and this is totally a subjective question based on preference. I don't think there's a standardized best practice for coding style.

For me, similarly to other languages, have the brackets line up vertically with the start of the function name. Having commas on separate lines can make it clear to separate args for some functions. As things get more complicated tab over.

I usually use this kind of indentation in a "code" style cell rather than an "input" cell, or use a standard text editor.

Here's my basic form:

```
func[x_] :=
Module[
    {
        foo = 1,
        bar = 2
    },

    If[cond,
        Print[foo];
        ,
        (* Else *)
        Print[bar];
    ];

    Switch[x,
        _Integer,
            Print[2 * val];
        ,
        _String,
            Print["2 " <> val];
        ,
        _,
            Print["Default"];
    ];


    (* Some random code from an answer I posted to a different question *)
    Export["test.gif",
        ImageResize[#, 100] & /@ 
            Table[
                ImageTrim[
                    Import["ExampleData/coneflower.jpg"]
                    , 
                    {{0, 0}, {m, m}}
                ]
                ,
                {m, 100, 50, -5}
            ]
        ,
        "GIF"
    ];
]
```

Comment: "many are going to find things they don't like slightly about my indentation " I think lots of people use this style. I certainly do.

Comment: @Szabolcs Even the answers which are very similar in this thread have subtle differences that some developers might feel strongly about. I just meant to say this isn't necessarily the "best practice" but at this point I'm not sure there is one, and there's likely to be other answers which are perfectly valid coming.

Nice that I picked up GeneralUtilities`HoldPrettyForm and @b3m2a1's nice indenter.