# How to automatically add indentation to selected block of code

Tags: front-end, editing

While editing a package file `.wl`, I just realized I need to wrap a block of code in `Module` and other stuff.  After doing that, I now need to indent the whole block of code with two extra spaces at the start of each line.  Is there a way in *Mathematica*'s editor to add automatically?

Comment: Also this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174904/38205