# Why does Mathematica indent comments the way it does?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

Whenever I type multi-line comments in Mathematica, the standard editor automatically performs indentation. I find the indentation rather curious and annoying, with some example frustrations posted below:

[image]

(note that I did not add any tabs or spaces in the top comment, and that there is NO linebreak after the comma in the bottom comment).

**What is the reasoning behind this convention for formatting / indenting? Are there any best practices for writing comments/documentation that actually use the automatic indenting in a useful way?**

Alternatively, is there a way to toggle the indentation off for *comments*, while keeping indentation for regular code?

(related: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/_mVsK6hDPao)

Comment: The notebook approach favors putting long descriptive comments into text cells next to the input cells they document.

Comment: You can use Code cells, no auto indentation no problem.

Comment: Or you use the standard Wolfram code editor for larger code, the so-called [Wolfram Workbench](http://www.wolfram.com/workbench/). Again, nearly no pain there (well, at least with comments).

Comment: Or use @halirutan's lovely [plugin for IntelliJ](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin#mathematica-wolfram-language-support-for-intellij-idea). Or use a `"Package"` notebook. Best practice for the FE, I'd say use a package notebook and use [some kind](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174904/38205) [of block indent](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39890/38205) [scheme](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48621/38205).

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments! I figure the main conclusion is that 1) thanks to Code Cells (either in "Package" or regular notebooks) and Text Cells, multi-line comments in regular Input Cells should rarely pop up. And 2), whoever is still unhappy with the current behaviour could use a different editor.

Comment: Another way to cheat the auto-identation is ending every line with a semi-column (;). That way the next line will not be automatically indented.