# About the behavior of comments in Mathematica

Tags: formatting

We all know that comments in mathematica are enclosed by `(*` and `*)` and what is written there is not run. Nevertheless I find myself annoyed by the behavior of what I write there. For instance sometimes when I write a `=` symbol inside comments the line breaks automatically and further text is introduced in the following line. This does not happen every time I use `=` so I do not know what is going on. Also things get aligned in a weird way if I start numbering the lines with `1-` `2-` and so on. Why does this happen How can I make this stop so that the text inside Mathematica does not et formatted automatically in a bizarre way?

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189599/5467), but there's no satisfactory solution.

Comment: What I do is to use `(* "this comment is entirely a string" *)`. The reason is that even comments are parsed as expressions, but strings are inert.