# Executing selected code

Tags: evaluation, keyboard, interface

In current *Mathematica* interface, if I select some piece of code and press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the code is evaluated in place. Replacing the selected part by the evaluated version.

**The question is:**

How can I create an equivalent, so that the evaluated code is presented below the current cell, instead of replace the selected part?

I'm studying `R`, and in RStudio you can just select some piece of code and press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to evaluate the result in the console. After some months using RStudio, I really miss this functionality in *Mathematica* interface. Maybe it's possible to hack `KeyEventTranslations.tr` to do that.

Comment: I'm confused, when you say "in a result cell below the current cell", how is that different than when I evaluate it by hitting Shift+Enter?

Comment: @JasonB probably in the fact that only selected part is evaluated and returned

Comment: @JasonB The difference is the Shit+Enter evaluate the whole current cell. I want to evaluate just the selected code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I wasn't even aware that Ctrl+Enter did something

Comment: @JasonB Imagine you have a cell full of variables, and want to know the current value of a specific item. Today you have to copy it into another location, and evaluate it.

Comment: This is almost what you need. Instead new notebook add SelectionMove after cell and NotebookWrite. Do you think it is a duplicate? [**55620**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55620/5478)

Comment: @Kuba nice link, I'll make some tests. I think that they are similar, not duplicate.

Comment: @Murta And I gave an answer... I can join you in retirement shelter...

Comment: @Kuba :p  I voted to close as duplicate. I believe that the reference is interesting.