# What's the proper way to do percent multiplication in Mathematica?

Tags: input, input-forms

I'm very new to Mathematica and I want to calculate percent multiplications. See below image. In `In[3]`, I pressed <kbd>space</kbd> after <kbd>50%</kbd> and then pressed <kbd>80%</kbd>. Mathematica automatically added the multiplication sign. In `In[4]`, I manually pressed <kbd>*</kbd>, the multiplication sign. Both seem not work. Where is the problem? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `%` represents the last output. See `Out` in documentation.

Comment: If you hate yourself, you can wrap everything with quantities: Quantity[50, "Percent"]*Quantity[80, "Percent"] means 50%*80%. The output will be 2/5 (not in percent), so not really useful. Why don't just use standard fractions instead, and multiply the result by 100 at the end to check the percentage?

Comment: You could define your own symbol, e.g., `¢ = 0.01`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - Rather than always use machine precision, I believe an exact value would be better, i.e., `¢ = 1/100`. At the end, machine precision can be coerced using `N` if desired.

Comment: @BobHanlon That was my first choice, but then I thought better of it. I cannot recall ever being interested in exact percentages. I'd say use tool that does what you want.

Comment: Could you use PercentForm[Fraction]? This can be evaluated in place to display as  100*Fraction% which can then be used in calculations such that an expression like 20%*300 gives 60.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The percent symbol `%` in *Mathematica* represents the last output `Out[-1]`, see the Documentation for `Out`. Hence the results you observe.

In principle you can use Inline Free-form Input for this: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> and type your <kbd>50%</kbd>, then press <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> again and type your next percent quantity <kbd>80%</kbd>, and so on:

[image: screenshot]

Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to perform the computation:

> ```
> 59/100
> ```

Alternatively you can take the [suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/205054/whats-the-proper-way-to-do-percent-multiplication-in-mathematica/206075#comment529130_205054) by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) and define your own percent symbol like `¢ = 0.01` and then type `50¢` instead of `50%` with similar effect:

[image: screenshot]

The symbol `¢` ([`\[Cent]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Cent.html)) has built-in alias <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>cent</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>. So there are two ways to type it in the FrontEnd: as `\[Cent]` or as <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>cent</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>. It is also possible to define a keyboard shortcut for it using one of the methods described here:

- [How can I set a keyboard shortcut to run a command?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16174/280)

Comment: I get the cent sign with the option key plus "4" but that may vary.

Comment: @MichaelE2 On my system (Win7) Alt+4 is a shortcut for the "Section" style.