# Could the decisions in the Find/Replace dialog also be made with the keyboard?

Tags: front-end, user-interface

Could the decisions in the Find/Replace dialog also be made with the keyboard bypassing all mouse actions? None of the buttons have a letter highlighted to make these decisions. To do this always with the mouse is quite annoying.
[image: Find-Replace dialog window]

It looks like currently only the text-entry boxes for **Find:** and for **Replace with:** can be switched by keyboard action (**Tab**).

- Would it be possible to manipulate the front end to make this
  possible?
- By some modification of a *.tr-file?
- Which one?
- What type of change?

(This question relates to Version 12.3 on Linux-86 64 Bit, if that matters.)

Comment: On a mac, you can use Command+G and Shift+Command+G to move next and previous.  Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: On my computer, neither **Fn+G**, **Ctl+G**, **Super-G** nor **Alt-G** are processed by the Find&Replace dialog. Probably one really has to tweak Mathematica's dialogs by proper frontend-actions. But I have no idea how to achieve it.

Comment: How about these?  
FrontEndTokenExecute["FindExpression"];
FrontEndTokenExecute[FrontEnd`ButtonNotebook[], "FindNextMatch"];
FrontEndTokenExecute[FrontEnd`ButtonNotebook[], "FindPreviousMatch"];

Comment: B flat, when I execute your code, it just opens the Find&Replace dialog with the old history click-selectable dropdown list for **Find** and for **Replace With**. But it does not modify it or assigns keyboard shortcuts. Do you have more ideas in your direction?

Comment: The first one seems to open the  Find&Replace dialog. The second ad the third one seem be the functions related to **Next** or to **Previous**. How can I assign these two to keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this.  See here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16165/how-can-i-set-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-a-command?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I prefer the add menu commands (the first option).

Comment: Also, look up FindSettings in the Wolfram Cocumentation to dial in the rest of the settings.