How to get the output of evaluating in place and append the output to the place
I am trying to use MMA for some engineering calculations, and the text cell contains both descriptive text and mathematical formulas. The example is as follows:
the resistor R1 = ρ×L/S = 1.8*10/2

I can select this part "1.8*10/2" and execute the "Evaluate in Place" menu function to obtain the calculation result, output will directly replace the selected content. The result is as follows
the resistor R1 = ρ×L/S = 9

But I want to keep the original calculation formula, append "=" and output behind the the selected content; My ideal result is as follows.
the resistor R1 = ρ×L/S = 1.8*10/2 = 9

How can I make it work? Any response will be appreciated.
PS: I believe the people who use mathcad will be interested in this.
Thanks for the guidance from @Domen and @wioiw, the following code works for appending output of evaluation in place. hope to provide some help to those who are interested.
MenuItem["Evaluate in &Place(Output Append)", KernelExecute[NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[],
        StringRiffle @ (Map[StringTrim, #]&) @ (Apply[Identity, #]&) @
            RowBox[{
                If[Head[NotebookRead@InputNotebook[]] === RowBox || Head[NotebookRead@InputNotebook[]] === BoxData, ToString[ToExpression[NotebookRead@InputNotebook[], StandardForm, HoldForm], StandardForm],NotebookRead@InputNotebook[]],
                "=",
                (ToString[#, InputForm]&)@ToExpression@NotebookRead@InputNotebook[]
            }]
    ];],


I never use Text cells myself. I do everything in code cell. You could try e=HoldForm[1.8*10/2]; Row[{"the resistor R1 = \[Rho]*L/S = ",e," = ", ReleaseHold[e]}] as an example. But actually the way I do all this is generate Latex from Mathematica and compile to PDF. It takes little more work, but it is the best way to do things :)  Mathematica should be just for the computation. The presentation and final report should be left to Latex. Do not use Mathematica like it is Microsoft word.

@Nasser, Thank you for your help and prompt. The system in engineering calculations is very complex, with a variety of formulas and many variables. Every inference and calculation require adding symbols, relationship descriptions, etc. Otherwise, it may be difficult for me to read it myself. So textual descriptions are necessary for me.

I understand. As far as I know WRI does not have a product like Mathcad where computation and output automatically presented side by side. So you have to do it "manually". May be someone else can suggest something. For me, I just run the notebook each time I change something, and then compile the Latex and look at the PDF. But may be this workflow is not suitable for everyone.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16165/how-can-i-set-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-a-command

@wioiw, thanks for replying, the version of my MMA is 14.0, some methods your hyperlink offers are deprecated and Invalid; At the same time, I also have some difficulties with implement "Evaluate in Place".

How often do you need to do this? Do you have a whole bunch of similar cells that you want to operate on? Or are you getting string input from a file and you want to operate on strings directly? I ask, because it sounds like you are fine using mouse/keyboard/menu commands, and all you'd need to do is make a copy of the desired expression, paste it to where you want it, and do the evaluate in place there. On the other hand, you tried to make a function to do this, which implies that this needs to be done repeatedly and that the input has a consistent format.

@lericr, Hi, I frequently engage in formula inference, symbol assignment, and operation in engineering calculations, interspersed with text descriptions to sort out the relationships between physical quantities, image display, and related feature descriptions.

@lericr, The entire process has a rigorous and unified contextual logic, but the calculation content of each unit is not complex, and it is an elementary mathematical operation of addition/subtraction/multiplication/division...etc. I did calculate physical formulas by copying commands and output back and forth before, but I found that this "evaluate in place" is close to what I want. I hope to find a way online to avoid the evaluated output directly replacing formulas.


Caution: You'd better back up this file, for unexpected syntax error may cause frontend to break down.

Try appending the below code to
$InstallationDirectory/FrontEnd/TextResources/$OperatingSystem/KeyEventTranslations.tr.
This code is only applicable to text cells, i.e. cells with style of "Text", "CodeText", etc.
Item[
    KeyEvent["x", Modifiers -> {Control, Shift}], 
    KernelExecute[NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
        StringRiffle @ (Map[StringTrim, #]&) @ (Apply[Identity, #]&) @ 
            RowBox[{
                NotebookRead@InputNotebook[], 
                "=", 
                (ToString[#, InputForm]&)@ToExpression@NotebookRead@InputNotebook[]
            }]
    ];], 
    MenuEvaluator -> "System"
], 


Thank you for your help, but I tried to copy your code into the file ~/Mathematica/14.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/KeyEventTranslations.tr, but pressing "Control+Shift+X" and did not result in any response or output

@YaoLi First of all, you need to confirm that this file is the one that your mma will use.

For me, it's not "X" but "Windows"

yeah,  my Operating System is Ubuntu 22.04, and KeyEventTranslations.tr is only in the directory ~/Mathematica/14.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/ and cannot be found elsewhere

It's quite weird. The code runs well on my machine.

My mma's version is 13.3.

my MMA's version is 14.0, It's really strange, even if I don't add your code, only modify other default key values in the file ~/Mathematica/14.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/KeyEventTranslations.tr , it doesn't work. What is the situation

The only possibility I can figure out is that MenuSetup.tr will override KeyEventTranslations.tr.

It's because of this shortcut key "X". I added your code to MenuSetup.tr and can activate it by clicking with the mouse, but the shortcut key was not available. When I tried to modify the shortcut key to G, it was activated quickly. Now it work fine, but couldn't be used in inline cell. For example I text inline cell by Ctrl+9 and input "1+1",  the result is StringTrim[RowBox[{1, +, 1}]] = 2

I don't know why inline cells aren't applicable, but the false result is completely same as evaluated in code cells.
